# error while creating new app rails with mysql db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

Hi everybody i'm new to rails and i installed everything ruby rails mysql and everything was done good and healthy, and when i tried to create a new app 'rails new blog' for example everything done good but whenever i add the '-d mysql' it stucks and give an error knowing that everything is installed good

Aikers-MBP:~ Aiker$ brew install mysql
Warning: mysql-5.7.16 already installed
Aikers-MBP:~ Aiker$

here i tried to install

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'` succeeds before bundling.
Aikers-MBP:kar Aiker$ rake db create
Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.6)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Aikers-MBP:kar Aiker$ gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: When it gives the error "Failed to build gem native extension" it gives one long error after that. Kindly copy-paste the error so that we know what is missing on your system.

Comment: yes and this is the whole error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is not able to find `lssl` library which is present in OpenSSL. To solve this issue you need to run:

```
brew install openssl
```

After this try installing `mysql2` gem. If this still fails then you might need to reinstall Xcode command line tools by running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Hope this solves your installation issue. :)

Comment: Happy to help @Aiker

Answer (score 0):

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/Aiker/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
/Users/Aiker/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161121-68854-12pc3sf.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for rb_big_cmp()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_PREFERRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_REQUIRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY in mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/lib
-----
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/Aiker/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/mysql2-0.4.5/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/Aiker/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/Aiker/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Aiker/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Aiker/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/mysql2-0.4.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```